# Too much buttons in one line

Tags: interface-design, user-experience

I have my result screen from some kind of quiz.

It has image with heart and text at the center. (I think this is the only place)

The question is how to place these pink action buttons. Firstly thought to place it in one line but then understand that better in UX way would place new tests at the top as action.

And now it looks like it has too much elements on the screen so I better place new tests at the bottom or not?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, people will automatically look at the top right to continue. It might look good putting the share button at the top left to even things out, and the retry button could then be centered. I don't think the text beneath the icon is needed, those icons are already popular and recognizable enough that most people will understand their meaning, or figure it out very quickly.  The pick is also very bright! Maybe tone it down. Just my suggestions, hope they help.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you shouldn't write any text below the buttons.

Frame the button graphics in solid coloured circles and align all three in a row with the share button in the centre and making it slightly larger than the other two.

Sorry I can't give a more visual answer don't have access to my equipment at the moment.

Comment: I disagree with this. Text helps users who aren't familiar with the icon to understand in addition to clarifies exactly what action it will have (a right arrow could mean several things)

Comment: I do agree with your point textless buttons aren't usually as easy to understand for some users. However an app seems much more intuitive and natural to use if developers use recognizable graphics for their buttons instead of shoving text under every possible button. If Zotov creative enough he can write "New Test" or any other type of text/graphic to denote a new test.

Answer (score 1):

First off, personally I don't feel like there are too many objects in your design. But I do still have issue with the design for UX purposes. This is because when I look at this application as a user, the "New tests" button does have more visual weight, signifying that I should probably click it which is good, but only by a fraction more than the "Share" and "Try this test again".

Instead, I'd play around with making the call to action more centralized and direct; something like this:

[image]

You'll need to play with the design of course, but by centering the call to action and giving it a solid outline and background it reinforces the fact that it should be clicked. Keeping the arrow retains the spatial direction.

Whether or not you stick with your original approach or with a button like I suggest, should make sure that users can swipe to the next page by dragging the page.

P.S. I'd consider changing "Try this test again" to "Redo this test" or just "Redo".